# how can i get value of FormBuilder angular and use it with property NgStyle

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-style

Hi guys i have a form with

```
this.crudForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: null,
      company: Company,
      document: Document,
      serie: Series,
      documentNumber: null,
      comment: '',
      note: '',
      reference: '',
      registryDate: new Date,
      validityDate: new Date,
      salesState: SALES_STATE_PRESALE,
      salesRef: Sales,
      igv: 0,
      igvTotalNC: 0,
      salesTotalNC: 0,
      netoTotalNC: 0,
      discountTotalNC: 0,
      igvAmount: 0

    });
```

and i want to get the value of salesState but in the front , so depending the value i do some stuff and im using this :

```
<div class="col-md-offset-7 col-md-1"><p class="align-status"><mat-icon matSuffix [ngStyle]="addStyles(crudForm.get('salesState').value)">stop</mat-icon>VENTA</p></div>
```

but is not working , its like im not getting the value.
Also de salesState gets diferent value depending the STATE of the Sale but that is working .
and this is the function on ts:

```
addStyles(a){
    let myStyle = {
      'color' : a === 2 ? 'green' : 'blue',
    }
    return myStyle
  }
```

Any ideas??

I would be very grateful

Comment: Is SALES_STATE_PRESALE a interface? If it so can you share it..

Comment: any particular reason why you called function in ngstyle where you can add directly to ng style the condition you have written inside the function?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
crudForm.controls['salesState'].value
```

as a parameter to addStyles function

like this:

```
<div class="col-md-offset-7 col-md-1"><p class="align-status"><mat-icon matSuffix [ngStyle]="addStyles(crudForm.controls['salesState'].value)">stop</mat-icon>VENTA</p></div>
```